# Nesting <li> inside <a>

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation system where the list items have padding on the top and the bottom, I want this whole area to be clickable.

I used to have the list items nested inside the anchor tag (`<a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>`)but when I validated my code, it said this wasn't allowed.

I've now swapped it round but now the whole list item area isn't clickable, only the text.

HTML:

```
<nav id="my-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="activities.html">Activites</a></li>
        <li><a href="team.html">Team Building</a></li>
        <li><a href="downloads.html">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="social.html">Social</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
header ul{
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    transition: all 350ms;
}

header li{
    float: left;
    padding-top: 61px;
    padding-bottom: 61px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
    transition: all 350ms;
}

header li a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Wire One', 'Arial Narrow', Verdana, sans-serif;
}

header li a:hover{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

header li:hover{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}

nav{
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap padding style from `li` to `a` tag:

```
header li a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Wire One', 'Arial Narrow', Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 61px;
    padding-bottom: 61px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: And, as @meagar mentioned, add display: block for <a>

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply your padding to the `<a>`, not the `<li>`, so that the `<a>` takes up the entire size of the `<li>`. You'll also need to set your `<a>` to `display:block`.

Answer (score 1):

Display the link as block:

```
nav a{
    display: block;
}
```